# Assigning Balls to Bins with Constraints on Which Ball to Go to Which Bin?

Tags: algorithms, np-hard

Let us say we have $m$ bins and $n$ balls. Every bin $i$ has capacity $c_i$ which is the number of balls that can be put into bin $i$. We have $c_i\geq1$ for all $i$. For each bin $i$, there is a collection of sets $S_i=\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{k_i}\}$ for given $k_i$. Each $X_j\in S_i$ is the set of balls that can be put into bin $i$. We have $|X_j|\leq c_i$ and $\emptyset\in S_i$ for all $i$.

For example, for $m=2$ and $n=3$, with $c_1=1$ and $c_2=2$, say we have $k_1=4$ and $k_2=5$. Say we have $S_1=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$. $S_2=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{2,3\}\}$. This means that ball $1$, $2$ or $3$ can be each assigned to bin $1$. Also, each ball can be assigned to bin $2$. Further, balls $2$ and $3$ can be together assigned to bin $2$. We might have an instance with $k_2=6$ and $S_2=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2\}\}$ for example.

We want to assign the maximum number of balls into the bins. Is this easy or hard?

Comment: If $S_i$ is a set of sets, have you tried to prove it NP-hard?  What partner problems have you looked at?

Comment: @D.W. See my edits

Comment: I'm still not clear on what the problem statement is.  I'd still like to see a general specification of what assignments are legal, and how this relates to the $S_i$.  Two examples are not a substitute for a general specification.  Also, are you sure you mean $\{\{2,3\}\}$ and not $\{\{2\},\{3\}\}$?  (Yet another reason we need a  general specification.)  I don't know what $c_i$-admissible or 2-admissible means; please define all non-standard terminology.  Also, I still don't see any indication of what you have tried or whether you have tried to prove the problem NP-hard and if so how.

Comment: If $S_i=\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{k_i}\}$, then each $X_j$ is a set of balls that can be put together into bin $i$.

Comment: That doesn't match your first example.

Comment: How is that? My first example is $S_2=\{\{2,3\}\}$, which means that both balls 2 and 3 can be put into bin 2.

Comment: You write "each ball can be assigned to bin 2.  Further, balls 2 and 3 can be together assigned to bin 2."  That sounds like you might have intended $S_2 = \{\emptyset,\{2\},\{3\},\{2,3\}\}$ to me.  But without a careful specification of the problem, who can say?  (Please ignore my earlier suggestion of $\{\{2\},\{3\}\}$; on re-reading what you wrote, that wasn't right.)

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the [Exact Cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) to your problem. The elements in the Exact Cover problem corresponds to the balls in your problem. For each subset $T$ in the Exact Cover problem, we construct a bin $i$ with $S_i=\{\emptyset, T\}$. Then there exists an exact cover if and only if all balls can be put into the bins. Hence, your problem is NP-hard.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting! For what values of $c_i$, is it still NP-hard? If $c_i=2$?

Comment: @zdm It is still NP-hard by a reduction from [Rainbow Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_matching).

Comment: So, can we say that exact cover problem is NP-hard even if each subset has size at most 2?

Comment: If we add the constraint that if $X_j\in S_i$ then all subsets of $X_j$ are also in $S_i$, can we still prove NP-hardness? If balls $\{2,3\}$ can be put into bin $i$ then ball $2$ can be put alone and also ball $3$ can be put alone.

Comment: The hardness of this problem comes from the constraint that you can only select one set from $S_i$. Exact 2-set cover has no such constraint. Comments are not for extended disccusion, you can ask a new question.